# Elasticsearch: queries with dynamic "Date range" filter, using value of a date field, with Kibana

Tags: date, elasticsearch, range, aggregation

I need to visualize the following, on the data of an ELK index, where 1 row equals one login on a website:

Given a keyword field `userID`, and a date field `date`, I would like to see "how many times user `userID` has logged in, between the date of the login, and *x* days before".

To solve the second half of the vizualisation, I need to do an aggregation that would allow me to display the count of a "date range", except I use the dynamic value of `date`.

Using a "date histogram" does not quite do the job. I need to do this extract for Machine Learning purposes, and the algorithm needs the count not to be a daily or a weekly histogram, but a count from the exact date, for each row.

Do you have advice or examples you could give me, regarding this query?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Would you be doing this for one user at a time, i.e. passing in the userID _and_ the last login date to the query?

Comment: @Val: So far, I've made a vizualisation on Kibana with an aggregation by user, which works, and one by date histogram, which works too, but is not quite what I wanted.
[link](https://imgur.com/a/NTTCdUg)

Comment: @Mike The final aim is to export the data in a matrix, where, for each login, I would have the number of previously made logins during the previous days. So I would preferably like to do this for my entire dataset.
So, to answer your question: yes, but for each row instead of one user at a time.